# NullPointerException while load csv using neo4j's apoc.periodic.iterate procedure

Tags: csv, neo4j

I'm loading csv file using apoc.periodic.iterate and apoc.load.csv, but I always fail and said there are NullPointerException :

```
neo4j> CALL apoc.periodic.iterate('
       CALL apoc.load.csv("http://128.194.9.150:9999/On_Time_On_Time_Performance_2018_1.csv", {}) yield map as row return row
       ','
       MATCH (sc:City {name: row.OriginCityName}), (tc:City {name: row.DestCityName})
       MERGE (sc)-[f:Flight {flightDate: row.FlightDate, flightNum: toInt(row.FlightNum)}]->(tc)
       ', {batchSize:200, iterateList:true, parallel:true});
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| batches | total  | timeTaken | committedOperations | failedOperations | failedBatches | retries | errorMessages | batch                                                                                          | operations                                                   | wasTerminated |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2851    | 570131 | 888       | 313800              | 256400           | 1282          | 0       |               | {total: 2851, committed: 1569, failed: 1282, errors: {`java.lang.NullPointerException`: 1282}} | {total: 570131, committed: 313800, failed: 256400, errors: } | FALSE         |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

BUT, while I using neo4j's load csv command to load this file, they are correct:

```
neo4j> LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "http://128.194.9.150:9999/On_Time_On_Time_Performance_2018_1.csv" as row
       MATCH (sc:City {name: row.OriginCityName}), (tc:City {name: row.DestCityName}) 
       MERGE (sc)-[f:Flight {flightDate: row.FlightDate, flightNum: toInt(row.FlightNum)}]->(tc)
       ;
0 rows available after 3395077 ms, consumed after another 0 ms
Created 255988 relationships, Set 511976 properties
```

the csv file come from the website: https://www.transtats.bts.gov/DL_SelectFields.asp?Table_ID=236&DB_Short_Name=On-Time

how should I load the csv file to avoid the NullPointerException ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you've obviously changed the default headers of the transtat-data but I assume you've verified those. The only thing I immediately see as an issue is that you have **parallel:true** in your apoc.periodic.iterate. Given the data (highly connected with many of the starting/ending points being the same) that's bound to cause issues.

Can you try with **parallel:false** ? That should give you exactly the same results as a regular LOAD CSV.

Hope that helps.

Regards,
Tom

**Update**

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (c:City) ASSERT c.name IS UNIQUE;

LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///488042997_T_ONTIME.csv" AS row
WITH [row.ORIGIN_CITY_NAME, row.DEST_CITY_NAME] as names
UNWIND names as cityName
WITH DISTINCT cityName as theName
CREATE (c:City {name: theName});

# Added 328 labels, created 328 nodes, set 328 properties, completed after 3308 ms.

USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///488042997_T_ONTIME.csv" AS row
WITH DISTINCT row.ORIGIN_CITY_NAME as ocn, row.DEST_CITY_NAME as dcn, row.FL_DATE as fdate, toInteger(row.FL_NUM) as fnum
MATCH (sc:City {name: ocn}), (tc:City {name: dcn})
CREATE (sc)-[f:FLIGHT {flightDate: fdate, flightNum: fnum}]->(tc);

# Set 1139338 properties, created 569669 relationships, completed after 38773 ms.
```

Comment: I had check the csv file header and load the data with "LOAD CSV" command and the load progress is ok, that takes 4 hours, that takes too much time, I think.
So, I using parallel:true option hopes to load the file quickly by parallel, so , if I want to load the relation ship data with much common begin/end node, there are no way to speed up the progress?

Comment: Four hours for 255988 relationships ? That sounds very excessive, that should only take a minute or so with a regular LOAD CSV. Do you have a (preferably unique)  index on the City name ?

Comment: I add a index on City.name and rerun the load , this time it takes 33minute, but that's also excessive than you said "a minute". 
I don't know whether my neo4j's configure is not right? I'm using 3.3.4 enterprise edition, and config dbms.memory.heap.initial_size=5g/max_size=10g. 
There are any way to optimize the load?

Comment: How many lines do you have in that file exactly (or send me the exact things you selected on transtats so I can get the same file) ? 33 minutes still sounds way too long for that amount of relationships. Did you set **USING PERIODIC COMMIT** ?

Comment: There are 570132 line in that file, I download it from : https://www.transtats.bts.gov/DL_SelectFields.asp?Table_ID=236&DB_Short_Name=On-Time  , with 2018 January's data. I extract the city from file and create :City node previously. I had use "USING PERIODIC COMMIT "  with commit batch from 10000 to 1000, that doesn't have obvious difference.

Comment: I've updated my answer including syntax that should get the job done quickly for you. I used **CREATE** over **MERGE** for the relationships (taking care to create exactly the same amount by using the WITH DISTINCT). The problem is that a couple of airports have a ton of flights between them and that's what is hitting the merge.